# get elements out of a list of matrices

Tags: r, matrix

Lets say i have a small list of matrices and want to extract the accessions of each matrix.
Is there any good way to do it except for looping the `attr()` function.

The matrix data:

```
tfmatrx<-list(

MA0275.1 = structure(c(0, 76, 0, 24, 0, 100, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                       100, 0, 0, 0, 100, 0, 72, 11, 16, 0, 53, 0, 0, 47), .Dim = c(4L, 
                                                                                    6L), .Dimnames = list(c("A", "C", "G", "T"), NULL), id = "MA0275.1", accession = "ASG1"), 
MA0276.1 = structure(c(0, 220, 8, 35, 0, 291, 0, 3, 61, 21, 
                       133, 10, 58, 54, 101, 12, 130, 0, 54, 0, 0, 11, 8, 147, 33, 
                       150, 8, 35, 80, 0, 92, 26, 0, 8, 249, 19, 0, 0, 256, 18), .Dim = c(4L, 
                                                                                          10L), .Dimnames = list(c("A", "C", "G", "T"), NULL), id = "MA0276.1", accession = "ASH1"), 
MA0277.1 = structure(c(63, 13, 13, 13, 100, 0, 0, 0, 100, 
                       0, 0, 0, 88, 13, 0, 0, 75, 0, 25, 0, 0, 0, 100, 0, 78, 16, 
                       3, 3, 81, 6, 6, 6, 63, 13, 13, 13), .Dim = c(4L, 9L), .Dimnames = list(
                         c("A", "C", "G", "T"), NULL), id = "MA0277.1", accession = "AZF1"), 
MA0278.1 = structure(c(64, 217, 425, 292, 104, 552, 150, 
                       192, 484, 111, 114, 288, 78, 401, 186, 333, 455, 51, 370, 
                       122, 248, 34, 670, 46, 98, 724, 143, 33, 52, 918, 7, 20, 
                       348, 346, 280, 24, 12, 3, 977, 6, 966, 5, 23, 4, 26, 6, 962, 
                       4, 9, 10, 4, 975, 47, 930, 7, 15, 892, 42, 16, 49, 487, 123, 
                       320, 68, 288, 140, 317, 254, 373, 110, 81, 434, 178, 367, 
                       184, 268, 402, 140, 341, 114, 435, 229, 241, 94), .Dim = c(4L, 
                                                                                  21L), .Dimnames = list(c("A", "C", "G", "T"), NULL), id = "MA0278.1", accession = "BAS1"))
```

I want to get all the accessions in a character vector or data.frame. I know how to do it for the first element in the list, but how to do it for all the accession instead?

The output i want to achieve here is:

> ```
> ASG1
> ASH1
> ASF1
> BAS1
> ```

`names(tfmatrix)` gives all the names but not the accession, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

How about

```
lapply(tfmatrx, attr, "accession")
$MA0275.1
[1] "ASG1"

$MA0276.1
[1] "ASH1"

$MA0277.1
[1] "AZF1"

$MA0278.1
[1] "BAS1"
```

You can also use `sapply`, which can be handy because the output is a vector (sapply tries to simplify the result as much as possible).

```
sapply(tfmatrx, attr, "accession")
MA0275.1 MA0276.1 MA0277.1 MA0278.1 
  "ASG1"   "ASH1"   "AZF1"   "BAS1"
```

Which is equivalent to above unlisted `lapply` solution.

```
unlist(lapply(tfmatrx, attr, "accession"))
MA0275.1 MA0276.1 MA0277.1 MA0278.1 
  "ASG1"   "ASH1"   "AZF1"   "BAS1"
```

Comment: `sapply` output might be more convenient.

Comment: I was just typing the `sapply` when I saw the new answer come up... too fast! For OP, swap, `lapply` with `sapply`, as @Roland says, the output might be more useful.

Comment: @Roman Lustrik  Very fast answer! thanks. lapply lets the structure of the output to a list and sapply changes it to a data.frame?

Comment: @SanderVanderZeeuw, `sapply` tries to simplify the type of output object. If for example, all entries of your list have the same number of elements, it'll result in a `matrix`. And if all elements of your list have only 1 value, then it'll simplify even further to give a `vector`.